# Convert Matlab code to C++; When storing only the desired 4-dimensional value in a variable and sending it as an argument

Tags: c++, matlab, translate

I am converting matlab code to C++.

When storing only the desired 4-dimensional value in a variable and sending it as an argument

If you look at the size of a specific variable loaded from a .m file in the MATLAB console, it is as follows.

```
size(someVar)
```

ans =
44100 14 72 2

And with a specific function, the data of the dimension starting from 1 is taken out and inserted as shown below.

```
someVar(1:2048, 5, 25, 2)
```

In this way, I am directly entering it as the second argument.

```
some_func(A, someVar(1:2048, 5, 25, 2));
```

**How do I implement loading the values of the four dimensions below in C++?**

```
someVar(1:2048, 5, 25, 2)
```

The values 5, 25, and 2 in the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th dimensions cannot be seen in Matlab.

```
a1 = someVar(1:2048, 5, 25, 2)
```

If I print a1 like below, I only see 2048 first dimension data. What happened?

```
size(a1)
```

ans =
2048 1

I translated matlab to C++

[matlab]

```
function c = some_func(a, b)
```

[c++]

```
extern void some_func(const coder::array<double, 1U> &a, const double b_data[], const int b_size[1], coder::array<double, 1U> &c);
```

**Why 1more argument in C++?
referencely c is retrun value**

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything that looks like range notation out of the box. You could spend the time and write your own, but I recommend looking into a third party library like Eigen or Armadillo to do the heavy lifting.  Even if you ultimately want to custom-cook your own solution, starting with a reputable third party library gives you a solid baseline to gage your efforts against.

Comment: Having a Duhhhhh moment. Can I assume that this `coder` thing IS a third party library and I'm just an old man shouting at the clouds?

Comment: Depending on the age of the system, returning `c` may have been prohibitively expensive because of the copying involved. Done right these days you'd get copy elision if you made `c` a local variable and returned it. Consider this poor-man's copy elision. Often copy elision is implemented much like this. The compiler adds a hidden parameter to the function, defines `c` at the call site, and passes `c` in as the hidden parameter.

Comment: This pattern can be useful when dynamic allocation is involved, and some call happens repeatedly in a loop. Instead of stressing out the allocator and possibly even fragmenting memory, the caller maintains a single object that can expand its internal capacity as needed, but does not need to do that every time around the loop.

Comment: I think you have at least two questions here. Please ask **one question** per post, and include a [mre]. See [ask]. Then [edit] your post. Thanks!

Comment: @user4581301 well, c++ has std::iota which is roughly the same as 1:2048